# How do I do a pristine checkout with git?

Tags: git, git-checkout

How do I return my working directory to the state it would be in if I made a new clone and checked out the current version?

For subversion I'd do:

```
$ svn status --no-ignore | awk '$1 == "?" { print $2 }' | xargs rm -r
```

and for mercurial:

```
$ hg status --ignored --unknown | awk  ' ( $1 == "?" ) || ( $1 == "I") { print $2 }' | xargs rm -r
```

So answers in the same line are fine. But something like `git checkout --clean -r b4a23` would be better.

Comment: Cheeky answer: `rm -rf * ; git clone <whatever>`

Comment: Is perfect answer. Can anyone come up with a more efficient equivalent?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

(prepare to loose all local, uncommited changes:)

```
git reset --hard
git clean -dfx .
```

As mentioned, you can use `git stash` to temporarily save a reference to your local pending changes on a 'pseudo branch' (i.e. a stash).

Comment: This will not delete any directories that are GIT repositories, if you wish to force the deletion of these repositories you need to specify -f twice (so -dffx). The package manager we use (Composer) occasionally downloads packages as repositories.

Comment: @Lewis are you referring to submodules?

Comment: Not always, Composer doesn't use submodules. It will, however, check out a git repository if a packaged version isn't available and the source code is stored in git.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@sehe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9166473/1690115), you may want to create an alias to make it easier.

```
git config --global alias.pristine '!git reset --hard && git clean -dffx'
```

Then you may just call `git pristine`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [git stash](http://book.git-scm.com/4_stashing.html) to save the current modifications off, then you can `git stash apply` to get your changes back.

Comment: Use `git stash -u` to stash untracked files, and `git stash -a` to stash ignored files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try `git reset --hard <revision>`

See this page for good examples for the reset command: http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-reset